# How save a snapshot of a chart in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

This is the method i'm using to save a snapshot of a chart in flex.

```
            private function takeSnapshot():void{
            var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(chart);
            var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
            var fileName:String = "chart.png";
            file.save(image.data,fileName);
        }
```

this method always ask saving path(give prompt) even if i give file name with path. how can i save snapshot without having a prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

I should have asked that in a comment (whether it's a web app or Air). But it seems i need some more reputation to do that :(.

So here is the deal , if your application is a flex web project, you can't save the screenshot file without having the save popup appear. But if it's an AIR application you can save it in a default location.

Answer (score 0):

For web app, you cannot save files directly to local file system. it's a browser security issue. If the snapshot is not going to be opened outside the app, the way to save it without prompt is to save it as shared object.